# Remote linux server to remote linux server large sparse files copy - How To?

Tags: linux, copy, large-files, virtual-machine, sparse-matrix

I have two twins CentOS 5.4 servers with VMware Server installed  on each.

What is the most reliable and fast method for copying virtual machines files from one server to the other, assuming that I always use sparse file for my vmware virtual machines?

The vm's files are a pain to copy since they are very large (50 GB) but since they are sparse files I think something can be done to improve the speed of the copy.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to copy large data quickly, `rsync` over SSH is not for you. As running an `rsync` daemon for quick one-shot copying is also overkill, yer olde `tar` and `nc` do the trick as follows.

Create the process that will serve the files over network:

```
tar cSf - /path/to/files | nc -l 5000
```

**Note that it may take `tar` a long time to examine sparse files, so it's normal to see no progress for a while.**

And receive the files with the following at the other end:

```
nc hostname_or_ip 5000 | tar xSf -
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to get all fancy, use `pv` to display progress:

```
tar cSf - /path/to/files \
   | pv -s `du -sb /path/to/files  | awk '{ print $1 }'` \
   | nc -l 5000
```

Wait a little until you see that `pv` reports that some bytes have passed by, then start the receiver at the other end:

```
nc hostname_or_ip 5000 | pv -btr | tar xSf -
```

Comment: thanks for the code snippet - very useful, scp is stupid slow :)

Comment: @pahoughton, no problem, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) with the option `--sparse`(possibly over ssh)?

From `man rsync`:

```
    Try  to  handle  sparse  files  efficiently so they take up less
    space on the destination.  Conflicts with --inplace because it’s
    not possible to overwrite data in a sparse fashion.
```

Comment: Note: the poster asked about CentOS machines, so the Solaris-is-broken bit is probably unnecessary.

Comment: Please note that rsync is terribly slow at copying sparse files.

Answer (score 1):

Since `rsync` is terribly slow at copying sparse file, I usually resort using `tar` over `ssh` :

```
tar Scjf - my-src-files | ssh sylvain@my.dest.host tar Sxjf - -C /the/target/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at http://www.barricane.com/virtsync

(Disclaimer: I am the author.)